# Angularjs - How to work with nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have following code which is showing data of two person namely Roshan and Ashwin and there is nested array which shows data of there friend name , constant, asalary, msalary etc.

```
allData = [{
        'id': '1',
        "name": "Roshan",
        "compname": [{
                "id": "1",
                "friend-name": "Ritik",
                "typeof": [{
                    "id": "2",
                    "constant": "per holiday"
                }],
                "salaries": [{
                    "id": "2",
                    "msalary": "1500",
                    "asalary": "18000"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "friendname": "Rohan",
                "typeof": [{
                    "id": "3",
                    "constant": "per employee"
                }],
                "salaries": [{
                    "id": "3",
                    "msalary": "18000",
                    "asalary": "25000"
                }]
            }
            ]
        },

        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Ashwin",
            "compname": [{
                    "id": "8",
                    "friend-name": "Amit",
                    "typeof": [{
                        "id": "9",
                        "constant": "per holiday"
                    }],
                    "salaries": [{
                        "id": "6",
                        "msalary": "11500",
                        "asalary": "118000"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "id": "23",
                    "friendname": "Kirti",
                    "typeof": [{
                        "id": "23",
                        "constant": "per employee"
                    }],
                    "salaries": [{
                        "id": "32",
                        "msalary": "180100",
                        "asalary": "253000"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
```

What I want.

I want to display name, friendname, constant, msalary and asalary using ng repeat.
How can I achieve this, help me.

Comment: provide correct json data it is invalid you did not close brackets properly

Comment: you can use ng-repeat multiple times it is easy but you have to provide correct json data

Comment: You could also try to do it and show us the result of your efforts. SO is not a website where we're going to do the work for you, we can help, that's just it.

Comment: Updated Json. @jitendravarshney

Comment: I had tried it but i m able to get only name but unable to get asalary. @Roux

Comment: it is also incorrect code @mohammed ,you did not used properly ,

Comment: ok I am checking it. and soon update it again. @jitendravarshney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using div tags for the ng-repeats, and for your specific Json :

```
<div ng-repeat="data in allData">
    <div>Name : {{ data.name }}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="comp in data.compname">
        <div>{{comp.friendname}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="type in comp.typeof">{{ type.constant }}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="salary in comp.salaries">{{ salary.msalary }} - {{ salary.asalary }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS : A point to be noted - There is inconsistency in your json, In one place, the attribute name is "friend-name" and in another place it is "friendname" which is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Your Json is not consistent through out.

```
<ul ng-repeat="ad in allData">
            <li>{{ad.name}}</li>
            <li>
                Friend Name
                <ul ng-repeat="cn in ad.compname">
                    <li>
                        {{cn['friend-name']}}</br>
                        Salaries
                        <ul ng-repeat="sal in cn.salaries">
                            <li>
                                MSalary: {{sal.msalary}}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                ASalary: {{sal.asalary}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </li>

        </ul>
```

If you want to access json field name with "hyphen"(-) in it you need to put square brackets[] around this.
Hope this example helps

Answer (score 2):

**Some observations :**

- Your `JSON` is invalid.
- object property having key with `-`(`friend-name`) remove them.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.allData = 
[{
 "id": "1",
 "name": "Roshan",
 "compname": [{
  "id": "1",
  "friendname": "Ritik",
  "typeof": [{
   "id": "2",
   "constant": "per holiday"
  }],
  "salaries": [{
   "id": "2",
   "msalary": "1500",
   "asalary": "18000"
  }]
 }, {
  "id": "2",
  "friendname": "Rohan",
  "typeof": [{
   "id": "3",
   "constant": "per employee"
  }],
  "salaries": [{
   "id": "3",
   "msalary": "18000",
   "asalary": "25000"
  }]
 }]
}, {
 "id": "2",
 "name": "Ashwin",
 "compname": [{
  "id": "8",
  "friendname": "Amit",
  "typeof": [{
   "id": "9",
   "constant": "per holiday"
  }],
  "salaries": [{
   "id": "6",
   "msalary": "11500",
   "asalary": "118000"
  }]
 }, {
  "id": "23",
  "friendname": "Kirti",
  "typeof": [{
   "id": "23",
   "constant": "per employee"
  }],
  "salaries": [{
   "id": "32",
   "msalary": "180100",
   "asalary": "253000"
  }]
 }]
}];
});
```

```css
span {
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in allData">
    <span>Name : </span>{{data.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="list in data.compname">
    <span>Friend Name : </span>{{list.friendname}}
      <div ng-repeat="leaveType in list.typeof">
      <span>Leave Type : </span>{{leaveType.constant}}
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="salary in list.salaries">
      <span>Msalary : </span>{{salary.msalary}}
      <span>Asalary : </span>{{salary.asalary}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

At first your Json has some corrections. Missing "]" corrected version is as follows,variable name cannot have '-' in it according to variable naming convention

```
      $scope.allData = [{
            'id': '1',
            "name": "Roshan",
            "compname": [{
                    "id": "1",
                    "friend-name": "Ritik",
                    "typeof": [{
                        "id": "2",
                        "constant": "per holiday"
                    }],
                    "salaries": [{
                        "id": "2",
                        "msalary": "1500",
                        "asalary": "18000"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "id": "2",
                    "friendname": "Rohan",
                    "typeof": [{
                        "id": "3",
                        "constant": "per employee"
                    }],
                    "salaries": [{
                        "id": "3",
                        "msalary": "18000",
                        "asalary": "25000"
                    }]
                }
                ]
            },

            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Ashwin",
                "compname": [{
                        "id": "8",
                        "friend-name": "Amit",
                        "typeof": [{
                            "id": "9",
                            "constant": "per holiday"
                        }],
                        "salaries": [{
                            "id": "6",
                            "msalary": "11500",
                            "asalary": "118000"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "id": "23",
                        "friendname": "Kirti",
                        "typeof": [{
                            "id": "23",
                            "constant": "per employee"
                        }],
                        "salaries": [{
                            "id": "32",
                            "msalary": "180100",
                            "asalary": "253000"
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            ]

<div ng-repeat="data in allData">
   <span>{{data.name}}</span>
   <div ng-repeat="companyName in data.compname">
      <span>{{companyName.friendName}}</span>
      <div ng-repeat="constantData in companyName.typeof">
         <span>{{constantData.constant}}</span>
         <div ng-repeat="salaryData in companyName.salaries">
            <span>{{salaryData.msalary}}</span><br/>
            <span>{{salaryData.asalary}}</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
</div>
```

All we have to keep in mind is the parent-child relationship in the JSON.For example "alldata" is the parent of overall JSON."compname" is the parent of "typeof","salaries" etc.Likewise it should be displayed.The "constant" and "salaries" div tag should be inside "compname" div tag as those are children of "compname"

Answer (score 0):

use nested ng-repeat here is plunkr and i have also corrected your json

```
   <div ng-repeat="data in allData">
       <div>Name : {{ data.name }}</div>
       <div ng-repeat="comp in data.compname">
           <div>{{comp.friendname}}</div>
           <span ng-repeat="type in comp.typeof">{{ type.constant }}</span>
           <span ng-repeat="salary in comp.salaries">
           <label>msalary:{{ salary.msalary }} </label><br>
           <label>asalary:{{ salary.asalary  }} </label></span>
       </div>
       <hr>
   </div>
```

[SEE PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/tVGTGALtKVUxcs4hWK3Y?p=preview)